# Getting confused with the rest operator and looping

Tags: javascript

I am going around in circles and struggling to find a solution; any education/guidance would really help me.

I may have a lot of arrays which I am doing string manipulation on.

I created a helpful debug function, to help me print the length of the elements in the arrays; post string manipulation.

This is the single array function, its working; however I'd like to use rest operators, as I'd like to feed it alot of arrays as parameters:

```
let arr1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
let arr2 = ["four", "five", "six"];
function debug_qty(arr) {
    let post_arr_filter = arr.map(function(word) {
        return `${word.length}`;
    });
    return post_arr_filter;
};
```

I have tried the below - but it only prints the first array, and when I append .length, I get 3, instead of 3,3,5 (the length of the individual strings).

```
let arr1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
let arr2 = ["four", "five", "six"];

function check_length(...args) {
    for (let arrs in args) {
        return args[arrs].length;
    };
};
```

My next attempt - this seems to find the two array lengths(i think), again not the child elements.

```
function calc_arr(...args) {
    let result = args.map(function(nums) {
        return nums.length;
    });
    return result;
}
```

I am going around in circles, so any mentoring would be most helpful. :)

Comment: have you tried `let arr of args` instead of `let arr in args`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show how you are calling these functions. If you are passing the whole array in without spreading, then you're calling the function incorrectly. Also, use `camelCase` for JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `map()` function twice, once to grab the arrays, and again to grab the words in them:

```js
let arr1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
let arr2 = ["four", "five", "six"];

function calc_arr(...args) {
    return args.map((arr) => {
       return arr.map((word) => {
           return word.length;
       })
    })
}

const res = calc_arr(arr1,arr2);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked brilliantly! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your `for...in` approach is that you are returning *inside* your loop (also note that you should really only use [`for...in` for iterating object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476), not array indexes). The `return` causes your function to exit and subsequently end the loop.

The issue with your last code snippet is that you're treating `num` as a single number, however, `num` is actually an array. When you do `...args` `args` becomes an array of all the parameters you pass it. If you pass `"one"` and `"two"` args would be `["one", "two"]`. If you pass `["one", "two"]`, `["three", "four"]`, `args` would then be an array of arrays `[["one", "two"], ["three", "four"]]`. For your `.map()` function to work, you really want the array you're working on to look like `["one", "two", "three", "four"]`, with all the elements in the one array. To get the array in this form you can use `.flat()`, or, since you're using `.map()`:

```js
function calc_arr(...args) {
  let result = args.flat().map(function(nums) {
    return nums.length;
  });
  return result;
}

let arr1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
let arr2 = ["four", "five", "six"];
console.log(calc_arr(arr1, arr2));
```

Alternatively, you could use `.flatMap()`, which flattens the array returned by the callback function into one larger array. This means the callback function of `.flatMap()` would need to return an array of counts:

```js
function calc_arr(...args) {
  return args.flatMap(arr => arr.map(str => str.length));
}

let arr1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
let arr2 = ["four", "five", "six"];
console.log(calc_arr(arr1, arr2));
```

If you want an array of arrays, you can use `Array.from` with a mapping function:

```js
const calc_arr = (...args) =>
  Array.from(args, arr => arr.map(({length}) => length));

const arr1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
const arr2 = ["four", "five", "six"];
console.log(calc_arr(arr1, arr2));
```

Comment: Thank you! I've learnt a new function "flat" through your stewardship, merging the arrays would have done the job and your snippet works. However, some of my arrays (post string manipulation) are 300+ in length. So the delineation in the arrays is quite helpful.

Comment: @NotAVeryGoodDeveloper so you actually want an array of arrays as your output?

Comment: Hey good evening - yes that is correct! array.from is another great function, I would have missed, thank you!!

Comment: @NotAVeryGoodDeveloper no worries ;)

Comment: Be aware that `flat` and `flatMap` are fairly recent additions to the language.  If you are unfortunate enough to be working with IE11, they won't work.   A lot of business-to-business stuff still uses IE.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher yeah, unfortunately it does have poor browser comparability. I would recommend using a polyfill or a transpiler such as Babel if comparability is an issue for OP